# C union assignment

Tags: c, unions

I have union that represent some structures that all uint32 type but with different bit-fields. can i do assignment of one union to other like this:

```
typedef union foo_u
{
   // raw
   uint32_t foo32;

   // interpretation 1
   struct
   {
      uint16_t a;
      uint16_t b;
   } foo_flavor1;

   //interpretation 2
   struct
   {
      uint32_t a        : 16;
      uint32_t b        : 12;
      uint32_t c        : 4;
   } foo_flavor2;
} foo;
foo a;
foo b;
a.foo32 = 10;
b.foo32 = 30;
b=a;
```

or i have to do the assignment like this:

```
b.foo32 = a.foo32;
```

Comment: `b=a` is perfectly OK.

Comment: Why don't you try this up in a compiler? There's even an online [one](https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c_compiler) if you don't have access to one.

Comment: Beware of [endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) and packing.

Comment: @HoriaComan: being accepted by a compiler and being conformant C can be different things: not all compilers are fully standard compliant (MSVC used to be a good example for a long time, unsure for last versions), and others support extensions to the standard

Comment: @SergeBallesta agreed on your point, but I think the question should have been asked as such. I was just making a point that it would have been easier to just test it out than to ask about it on SO. At the end of the day, if OP is asking for a work project, they're stuck with whatever compiler the company uses, rather than what the standard says and what the set of compilers implement. Granted, it's _good_ for this question to exist for future reference.

Answer (score 8):

```
b = a;
```

It's totally OK to do this.

For structures and unions, assigning one to another of the same type is well-defined by the standard, and it's guaranteed that after the assignment, they should contain exactly the same data (padding excluded, if present).

Comment: It should be noted that if we write some part of `a`, then we're only allowed to access that part of `b`.